# Declaring a global variable in java scriptlets

Tags: java, html, scriptlet

I have a html file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<% int i=1; %>
<span name="page2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the span page2 of the above file i inserted a new page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<% if(i=1) { %>
<p>1</p>
<% }
else { %>
<p>2</p>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working in Websphere portlet factory to insert the second page into first page.

The problem is the variable 'i' in the second file cannot be resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each jsp file is individually compiled in the `server` . when the second file is compiled it doesnt know the declaration of `int i`.

By default it is stored to the `page` scope ,

> page scope means, the JSP object can be accessed only from within
>   the same page where it was created

You can rather set it ,

```
application.setAttribute( "globalVar", i);
```

in the application scope to access it through out the application

Comment: when i do this does the variable i become global..?

Comment: you should use get the value again like this , `int i= (Integer) application.getAttribute("globalVar");`

Answer (score 3):

Anything you write inside scriplet will become content of service method of Servlet.

So

```
<% int i=1; %>
```

will be

```
public void service(request,response){
   int i=0

}
```

You can use JSTL tags because it is best practice to avoid usage of scriplets

```
<c:set var="i" value="1" scope="request/session/application"/>
```

Your whole example without using script becomes like this

```
<!--You have to import JSTL libraries-->
html>
<body>
<c:set var="i" value="1" scope="application"/>
<span name="page2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Accessing it into another JSP.

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- Expression language-->
<p> ${applicationScope.i eq 1?1:2} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To access you just need you use scope which you are using. For e.g ${requestScope.i} or ${sessionScope.i} And you should avoid using scriptlets. Never write any Java code in JSP.